# Single Page Applications and MVC - Is it either / or?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I've spent the last couple months learning and developing a couple applications using MVC 4. I really like the simplicity of of the MVC model and the Razor View engine. However, now I'm now starting to hear more and more about Single Page Applications. Is this a case of SPAs being an improvement over MVC, and gradually replacing MVC? Or is this more a case of SPAs serving a particular type of application and MVC serving another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPA's are more suited to web applications such as Gmail rather than a typical website (by typical, i mean a site with normal text pages, some forms, and maybe even a shopping cart type thing).

I wouldn't go as far as to say SPA will replace MVC, but i believe they hold their own individually, but more importantly the SPA type frameworks like AngularJS, can also work together with MVC to create a more powerful website.